# Disadvantage of HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have to encode a field so to make it secure of script injection.

I know  I can use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and Decode, but this method for HI-ASCII characters goes out of the range of the field size in database and I dont want to change the size of data field column.

Instead if I use HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode, it works fine because it does not encode the HI-ASCII characters.

Is it safe what can be the disadvantages of it.

Comment: Don't store encoded input in the database. Only encode it before outputting it.

Comment: Are you storing encoded data in the database?

Comment: I'd see Developer Art's comment as an answer, perhaps you might want to add that certain inputs should be rejected even before storing.

Comment: @Darin,yes I am storing encoded data in the database.

Comment: @Developer Art, if the html to be encoded is big, shall I store it without encoding or encode it once and then display without encoding it again and again.

Answer (score 7):

From [HttpUtility..::.HtmlAttributeEncode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdek0zbf.aspx):

> The HtmlAttributeEncode  method converts only quotation marks ("), ampersands (&), and left angle brackets (<) to equivalent character entities. It is considerably faster than the HtmlEncode  method.
>
> The string result from the HtmlAttributeEncode method should be used only for double-quoted attributes. **Security issues might arise** when using the HtmlAttributeEncode method with single-quoted attributes.

However it is not a usual practice to store the encoded input in the database. It is difficult to predict how much longer an encoded version will become.

Much better is directly store the input, and only encode it when needed (when you output it in HTML).

Comment: @Developer Art, thanks for your response, can you help me to differentiate between double-quoted attributes and single-quoted attributes.

Comment: @Developer Art, if the html to be encoded is big, shall I store it without encoding or encode it once and then display without encoding it again and again.

Comment: @VinayPandey My understanding is that attribute is referring to html elements therefore a single-quoted attribute looks like `<a href='#page' />` while a double-quoted attribute looks like `<a href="#page" />` so the output you would use this method on in this example is `#page`. If you're worried about performance with encoding every time on output instead of just once on input, write a quick test and time how long encoding takes.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data without encoding may cause SQL injection.

Comment: ... unless you properly encode things when putting them into SQL statements.