# Input returned in response (reflected) asp.net vulnerablility

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

I have a web application running on asp.net webforms on framework 4.0. A third party company performed a security assessment and identified couple of vulnerabilities, one of which says.

- S.No.3:  Input returned in response (reflected)
- Risk: Medium
- Description: Reflection of input arises when data is copied from a request and echoed into the application's immediate response.

As POC they have shared below image in which input value is highlighted in yellow[image] I searched the internet but i am not able to understand about what to do with this.  How can i resolve this vulnerability. What is the solution for this.

Comment: You should use [HtmlAttributeEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463278/1115360) when setting the value of an HTML tag's attribute. More info: [Do I encode ampersands in <a href…>?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705601/1115360)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ModelState.Clear();` on serverside so that your input will not get reflected in the response.
For additional info about `ModelState.Clear()` [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2678956/18721523)